# Angular selected option ignoring first array value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to use `localStorage` to remember the user's selection and set the selected option accordingly on their next login.

The `select` options populate correctly as shown below.

[image: populated options]

When the index is 1 or above it works correctly, but whenever the first value is selected no value is selected by default on the next reload.

I have illustrated this below:

index of `0` on load
[image: Index is 0]

index of `1` on load
[image: Index is 1]

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<select name="ipSelect" data-ng-model="selectedOption">
    <option ng-repeat="ip in adapters track by $index" data-ng-value="adapters.indexOf(ip)">{{ip}}</option>
 </select>
```

In the controller

```
ipcRenderer.on('device_ips_loaded', (event, adapters) => {
    let storedIndex = localStorage.getItem('defaultIp') || 0
    console.log('Adapters: ' + adapters)
    console.log('storedIndex: ' + storedIndex)
    $scope.adapters = adapters
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.selectedOption = adapters[storedIndex]
    })
    console.log('selectedOption: ' + $scope.selectedOption)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [**`ngOptions`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

See it *working*:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectedOption = '1';
    $scope.adapters = ['25.91.79.201', '192.168.0.14']
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="key as ip for (key, ip) in adapters" ng-model="selectedOption">
      <option value label="Select an adapter" hidden></option>
    </select>
    <pre ng-bind="selectedOption"></pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```